# How to display the content of MS Office 2007/2010 files on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, docx

How can we display the content of MS Office 2007/2010 files (specially .docx) in iOS 3.2 (ipad)?

Comment: i tried UIWebView to view the .doc and .docx files but my trials ended unsuccessfully !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using this code snippet :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourcePath ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

ironically I found that the **UIWebView** is capable of viewing these types but only on the iPad physically, it will not view the files in the simulator.